# Specify home directory in appsettings?

Tags: macos, .net-core

In my appsettings.json I want to have

```
{
  "Location": "~/"
}
```

So that I can get some files from that folder

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(settings.Location, *.txt);
```

But that currently looks in `/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/~` so I have to put

```
{
  "Location": "~/Users/myusername"
}
```

which won't work on someone else's machine

Comment: Does `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)` still work?

Comment: Should've probably have specified that for Windows it's in a different location that's not in the home directory